# How-to .htaccess redirect to www without loosing GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

need some help. i have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)/ catalog.php?id=$1
```

with this redirect i don't receive (http://www.example.com/catalog/abc/)

```
GET['id']
```

how to receive GET['id']?

Comment: added RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php

Comment: i ask about such version

Comment: -1 You've asked `How-to .htaccess redirect to www without loosing GET` even though your _actual_ problem has nothing to do with `www` or infact losing (existing) get arguments. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd rule needs 2 flags:

- QSA - Query String Append
- L - Last

Overall your .htaccess should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]+)/?$ catalog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

QSA flag in 2nd rule will make sure to presserve any existing query string while adding a new query parameter `id`

Comment: How does QSA help with OP's problem when `id` is already appended?

Comment: The question is not about how to *presserve any existing query string*.

Comment: @Oswald: My answer is not just about adding QSA. There are certain options, RewriteBase, L flag and different pattern in 2nd RewriteRule.

Comment: i just add yet one string in .htaccess RewriteRule ^catalog/ catalog.php